# Use header('location') to redirect to PDF files doesn't work

Tags: php, google-chrome, pdf, header, location

I have a weird issue with PHP's `header('location: XXX')` function.
I have a URL-shortening website I built for my personal uses, that works like any other service (bit.ly, goo.gl). It works great, but I can never use it with PDF files.

For example, with this [Example PDF file](http://unec.edu.az/application/uploads/2014/12/pdf-sample.pdf), I used bit.ly to shorten it: http:// bit.ly /29l4ueo (remove spaces)

As you can see, it's impossible to get to the file. It looks like the link has a problem, but why would it?

The same happens with my website. I use the following line for redirections:

```
header('Location: '.$long_url); 
exit();
```

It acts like bit.ly - you can't open the URL. You can test it [here](http://teik.co/testpdf). **It works if I click it, but it doesn't work if I type it manually to the address bar.**

Is there any special header I can include, or any change I can make to my code in order to make it work with any link, including PDF files?

Thanks!

**edit:** seems like it's a specific problem with Chrome. It doesn't happen if you use Firefox, Edge or Opera.

Comment: Did you try specifying the content type ? `header("Content-type:application/pdf");`

Comment: Yes. It has no effect.

Comment: Is the file internal or external ?

Comment: External in all cases

Comment: it actually works perfect here on Firefox, Opera, and Edge, i guess your problem is specific to Chrome (or Safari?)

Comment: I use chrome. That's weird - is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: I just tried to serve the file with `readfile` and it worked, check out my answer

Comment: I'm using chrome right now, and the test link works fine here you have. Chrome does not download the file though, it opens it in a pdf reader window/tab. Where I can download or print from there. I also manually typed it in, also with https, and also with www. ... all three ways of typing it in, I get the file ..... ????

Answer (score 1):

Here you go :

```
header("Content-type:application/pdf");
// I used the first PDF I could find on the internet for the demo
readfile("https://www.rankya.com/assets/advancedSearchOperators.pdf");
```

To use `readfile` you need to make sure that `allow_url_fopen` is enabled.

Another option would be the refresher, displaying a message before the redirect :

```
header("refresh:3;url=https://www.rankya.com/assets/advancedSearchOperators.pdf"); 
echo 'You\'ll be redirected in about 3 secs. If not, click <a href="https://www.rankya.com/assets/advancedSearchOperators.pdf">here</a>.';
```

exit;

Comment: Thats a lot of overhead for what he is trying to build. Your answer reads in the file in the php server, to output the whole thing as a file directly. It does not direct the user to the actual file location.

Comment: You're right, no redirection, just reading and outputting the file :/